# What's the correct term, 'Clone' or 'Duplicate'?

Tags: terminology

In my software program there is a list of items. Users can duplicate/clone one of these items to slightly alter.
[image]

What's the correct terminology to use on the button that performs this action? 'Clone' or 'Duplicate'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Duplicate is a more user-friendly terminology for the average joe.
- Clone works better for techies.

Comment: Where did you base this on?

Comment: I don't have external data to back up Oluwatobi's answer, but we recently rolled out a feature that would clone records in an internal web app. The word "clone" confused a lot of our users, so we switched to duplicate.

Comment: Agree - "Duplicate" is used in office software and office tools. The average non-tech user would be more familiar with the term "duplicate", e.g. the concept of creating document duplicates, duplicating records or rows in Excel and even the "duplicate" button on the photocopier.